# SQL - LEFT JOIN entry times

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a problem with SQL and I don't really get what I'm doing wrong. I have two tables and want to replace in Table1 with one entry from Table 2. This works fine but it times. To clarify, Table1 has 20 entries and Table2 aswell but my output has 400 entries. So each entry 20 times.

So here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Table1
|Name     |FullName  |Size      |
+---------+----------+----------+
|File1    |C:\File1  |8923749343|
|File2    |C:\File2  |3475873758|
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Usually there are twenty entries, but for now 2 should be enough.

```
Table2
|FullName |CopyName  |Name      |
+---------+----------+----------+
|www\File1|C:\File1  |File1     |
|www\File2|C:\File2  |File2     |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

My goal now is getting *Table1* with *FullName* from *Table2* instead of *Table1*.
What I tried:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.FullName, t1.Size 
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.FullName=Table2.CopyName;
```

This is what I got:

```
Table1
|Name     |FullName  |Size      |
+---------+----------+----------+
|File1    |www\File1 |8923749343|    
|File1    |www\File1 |8923749343|
|File2    |www\File2 |3475873758|
|File2    |www\File2 |3475873758|
+---------+----------+----------+
```

This is what I want:

```
Table1
|Name     |FullName  |Size      |
+---------+----------+----------+
|File1    |www\File1 |8923749343|
|File2    |www\File2 |3475873758|
+---------+----------+----------+
```

So technically I got it right but for some reason it timed. Here i got each twice, on my original try each 20 times. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.FullName, t1.Size 
FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     Table1 t1
     ON t1.FullName = t2.CopyName;
```

Your query has two references to `Table1`.  Hence, you are getting a Cartesian product between that and the actual `JOIN` that you want.

Comment: Oh right forgot about that *facepalm*, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should remove that line from your query ", Table2 t2"

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.FullName, t1.Size
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.CopyName=t1.FullName;
```